# How to call a function with a variable?

Tags: c++

Hello so i am wanting to call a function with a variable like this for eg

```
void Test(){
    printf(":P");
}
void Tests(int foo){

}
void Tester(unsigned int r){
   int r = Test(r);
   /*Just an example*/ 
   Trace(r);
}
```

Comment: what is the question ? i see none ...

Comment: im wanting to declare a varable like int i = Test();

so when i want to call it i can just call i and it will run Test();

Comment: At a minimum, `Test()` should not be returning `void`, then.

Comment: so it should be an int?

Comment: I think maybe the OP is looking for function pointers ?

Comment: @user3424536 what's stopping you from writing `int i = Test();` ?

Comment: @Raxvan, the compiler probably, since the return type of `Test` is `void`.

Comment: well the function that i am using needs to be void. is there any way you can convert an int to void? or vise versa?

Comment: @Jefffrey yes , i wanted to get more info on the actual question.

Comment: @TheForestAndTheTrees: the question is admittedly vague and ambiguous, but there are enough clues to suggest that the OP wants to call functions via a variable, i.e. a function pointer.

Comment: @PaulR On reflection I think you're right.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void Test()
{
    printf(":P");
}

int main()
{
    void (*foo)();
    foo = &Test;

    (*foo)();

    return 0;
}
```

Please add details in your question. Now it is hard to help you.

Comment: It may help to point out to the OP that `foo` is a *function pointer.*

Comment: Also, much of your function pointer syntax is unnecessary. You don't need the ampersand when taking the address of a function, and you don't need to dereference it when calling it. I.e. `foo()` is sufficient.

Comment: Jonathon, I completely agree with you: it is not necessary, but allowed. I am trying to be as clear as it is possible, so I add these constructions. In the real world it is better to take into account code rules of a team.

Comment: Agreed, just pointing it out. My style reference is typically the Linux kernel, where they avoid any unnecessary constructs like the plague.